# Fix ugly bold fonts in Firefox 18+

Tags: 12.04, firefox, fonts

I am using Firefox 19 at the moment. As of Firefox 18 or even earlier, I noticed that bold fonts on some pages look horrible and unreadable.

For example, go to this [link](https://github.com/ooyala/barkeep/issues/218).

In my Firefox 19, the page looks like this

[image]

How can I fix this so that those unreadable fonts become readable again?

I guess the Ubuntu is in some kind of collision with TTF or similar fonts.

Comment: This link http://superuser.com/questions/536183/how-to-fix-ugly-fonts-in-firefox-18 did NOT help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your computer's font settings. Github's font stack looks like this:

```
Helvetica, arial, freesans, clean, sans-serif
```

This means that if you have the first one it comes across, it will use it. If you don't have it, it moves on to the next one and so on down the list, until it gets to one you have, or the default system sans-serif font.

If your system font is something less horrid, then check Firefox's default font. In Preferences, find "Fonts & Colors" and check the value of the font and change it if needed. [For more info, check out Firefox's help page.](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/change-fonts-and-colors-websites-use)

Answer (score 4):

Solved based on Shauna's link. Simply disallowed websites to use their own custom fonts.

**Custom Fonts**

Some websites have custom fonts, to disable them:

1. Click on the Firefox button and then select **Options**, and then again click **Options**. Or, on the menu bar, click on the **Edit** menu and select **Preferences**.
2. Select the **Content** panel. Under **Fonts & Colors**, click the **Advanced...** button.

   [image: "Advanced..." button]
3. In the window that opens, *uncheck* the box next to **Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above**.

   [image: Allow pages to choose their fonts]
4. Click OK to close the Fonts window. Click OK to close the Options window. Click Close to close the Preferences window. Close the Preferences window.